# Is there a more elegant solution to the bwa-mem: paired reads have different names error?

Tags: bwa, errors

I'm currently trying to run bwa-mem on Influenza substrains using the following command:

```
~/bwa mem h5n1_1_cons.fa h5n1_1_read1.fq h5n1_1_read2.fq
```

h5n1_1_cons.fa is the consensus sequence for substrain h5n1_1, and the fq files are paired end reads 1 and 2. Running the program gives me this error:

```
[mem_sam_pe] paired reads have different names: "JQ714243-920-1", "JQ714243-920-2"
```

Visual inspection shows that the read names are identical until the last character. I have found a package (bbmap) with a utility, bbrename.sh, that renames the sequences, producing:

```
./bbrename.sh in=h5n1_1_read1.fq out=fixed prefix=h5n1_1
```

which yields the following output

```
-bash-4.2$ head fixh5n1_1_read1.fq
@h5n1_0
gaaaatgtctcaggagttgatgcatggtgtttaatctttggtttgcgctg
+
@4>C5?7FA?9@@@;1,-4B+E??4E9,DA>6CB)*2.)?7/.'65+75/
@h5n1_1
catcagttggattttgcctaaggatgtccaccatccttatcccaccaatt
+
7(9?)=C3AEF+@@F=C-E>EE57CD:;'?.*?7;>:3>2.;29..)=2'
@h5n1_2
catgcatttgttggaataatgttctcacaaatcaactgtattgaccgctg
```

This fixes the problem and allows BWA-MEM to work. However, header information is discarded. Is there another way to ensure the header names are the same while retaining all header information?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a few examples of the read names in your original input files. The output of `awk 'NR % 4 == 1{print $1}' h5n1_1_read1.fq | head` and `awk 'NR % 4 == 1{print $1}' h5n1_1_read2.fq | head` for example.

Comment: Since you mention bbmap already, why not use that for mapping your reads altogether? It is after all called bb*map*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the read name lines only contain things like `@JQ714243-920-1` and nothing else, then `sed -i '1~4 s/-[12]$//' file.fastq` (N.B., example updated a bit for safety, thanks to @terdon) will remove the `-1` and `-2` suffixes.

However, you should try to figure out **why** the read names were munged into that form to begin with (at least Illumina machines won't produce that, I don't know about others).

Comment: You could also replace the the second - with a space. Most mapping tools only regard the part of the id before the first space as the read name.